getting headers information in php which is sent from flutter web app
in flutter side i use:
final headers = <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'appsessionid': appSessionId ,
        };

        final response = await http
            .post(Uri.parse('${serverAdd}\login\\signUp.php'),
                headers: headers, body: json.encode(data))
            .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 15), onTimeout: () {
          return http.Response('Error', 408);
        });

to send some information, but in my php side i cant get the appsessionid value, my php side code headers and codes are here:
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$appSessionId = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_APPSESSIONID']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_APPSESSIONID'] : null;


i expect i can get the appsessionid in php side

Try apache_request_headers() to fetch all HTTP request headers from the current request. It returns them in an array so you can print_r and preview.

Custom HTTP headers might be unavailable in PHP due to the server configuration in front of the PHP SAPI. In other words, ensure your web server configuration passes the custom header(s) through. Without the details about your server configuration, it is difficult to give a more specific answer.
